# Difference between angular submit and ngSubmit events?

Tags: angular

I'm building a form in an Angular 2 application.

Html gives me the submit event. In Angular I could listen to this event using a (submit) event binding. On top of that, Angular adds the ngSubmit event, which I could listen to, using (ngSubmit).

I understand that submit comes from html, and ngSubmit from Angular. What I don't understand is why I would need to listen to a special ngSubmit event, instead of the normal submit event.

I created a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/p8XsiS2YKtNAHjuwZHqx?p=preview) that listens to both events and both seem to do the same thing.

What is the difference between listening to (submit) and (ngSubmit)?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <form (submit)='onSubmit(form)' (ngSubmit)='onNgSubmit(form)' novalidate #form='ngForm'>
      <input type='text' name='input' [(ngModel)]='input' required>
      <input type='submit' value='Submit' required>
    </form>
  `,
})
export class App {

  input : string;

  onSubmit(form): void {
    console.log(`submit: ${this.input}, valid: ${form.valid}`);
  }

  onNgSubmit(form): void {
    console.log(`ng-submit: ${this.input}, valid: ${form.valid}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: I though ngSubmit is required when you intent to use the validators that come with Angular

Comment: That sounds logical. But in the above example, in both the onSubmit and the onNgSubmit methods, $form.valid is already updated correctly. So what is the difference then?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> ngSubmit ensures that the form doesn’t submit when the handler code
>   throws and causes an actual http post request.

from https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/21/template-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html

Comment: can somebody explain what is meaning of 'when the handler code throws'?

Comment: It happens when the code that you run when you submit the form throws an error.

Comment: "...causes an actual http post request." But to which URL? There's no "action" attribute on the <form> tag. Aren't all http requests in an Angular app the result of explicit Ajax calls (using HttpClient, etc.) instead of requests initiated by the browser?

Comment: @Leogout - can you give me a real example?

Answer (score 42):

**`submit`**: It is html default form submit event, it will call underlying method when form gets submitted.

**`ngSubmit`:** Is [host binding](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.4/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts#L62) situated on `form` element. Basically it [prevent default `submit` event](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.4/packages/forms/src/directives/ng_form.ts#L140-L144) of browser(which can be form `post`) by returning false. Eventually you can prevent traditional `PostBack` calls or page reload due to form load. This way you can validate your form & submit it to server by manual ajax from `Component` code

Comment: It is still hard to understand it.

Answer (score 3):

None of the answers clearly explains as the explaination given in this link.

Submit- triggers a post call to browser URL/server.

Ngsubmit- calls local angular component to do something useful like form validation BEFORE postback to browser url/server.
It can be used to hijack form submission or control submit process.

https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/forms/submitting-and-resetting/

Comment: That link describes the difference between  an ordinary HTML form with a submit button, not the difference between the Angular event bindings `(submit)` and `(ngSubmit)`, which is what the OP asked.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see there is already nice answers to this question here. But just to elaborate a bit more for some people this might help:

with default html behavior when you press submit button it will submit the form and make a post request to the specified url

```html
  <form action="SOME_URL_TO_CALL_ON_SUBMIT" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="input" required>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
```

**Note that:**

> if a button is placed `inside a form` and `does not have the type attribute` OR `type="submit"` it will just submit the form

if you set `type="button"` then the button `would not` submit the form and you need to trigger submit event manually

```html
  <form id="myform" action="SOME_URL_TO_CALL_ON_SUBMIT" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="input" required>
    <button type="button">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <script>
    let form = document.getElementById('myform');
    form.submit();
  </script>
```

you can also use `onsubmit` event on form, `same as (submit)` in `angular` case

```html
  <form action="SOME_URL_TO_CALL_ON_SUBMIT" method="POST" onsubmit="submitForm()">
    <input type="text" name="input" required>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
```

Now if you want to customize your form a bit more like doing more validation and do other stuff like a custom http request, you should remove action and method attributes and `prevent the default` behavior of form. otherwise the page will be refreshed after submit

```html
  <form onsubmit="submitForm(this)">
    <input type="text" name="input" required>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
  <script>
    function submitForm(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      // Do you stuff here
    }
  </script>
```

angular `ngSubmit` will just do the same thing for you and prevents the default behavior

```html
  <form (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
    <input type="text" name="input" [(ngModel)]="input" required>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
```

```js
    submitForm() {
      // Do you stuff here
    }
```

Answer (score -4):

submit: If function is not define on its click event then it never post the data.

(ngsubmit)="saveEmployee(ngForm)": its post the ngform value to console in angular