# submit vs ngSubmit in Angular 2

Tags: angular

In order to submit a form in Angular 2 we can either use form's "submit" or "ngSubmit" event.

```
<form #frm="ngForm" (submit)="add(frm.value)">
  ...
</form>

<form #frm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="add(frm.value)">
  ...
</form>
```

Would like to know whats the difference between the two ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between angular submit and ngSubmit events?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41448038/difference-between-angular-submit-and-ngsubmit-events)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

from this tutorial, https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/03/21/template-driven-forms-in-angular-2.html

> However, ngSubmit ensures that the form doesn’t submit when the
>   handler code throws (which is the default behaviour of submit) and
>   causes an actual http post request. Let’s use ngSubmit instead as this
>   is the best practice:

Comment: Using angular@4.0.1 if I put a `throw new Error('rekt');` line in the function that my `ngSubmit` calls, it will still do an actual http request to the server when it dies. The only way I know to stop this right now is to follow this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40055510/232629 (TL;DR: Send in `$event` from the template, and call `event.preventDefault();` as the first thing in your `ngSubmit`)